# Radgrid: Referencing control on same row as textbox in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using Telerik Radgrid control in my C#/ASP.NET project. I have a GridTemplateColumn in my RadGrid. In that template column I have a textbox. In the OnTextChanged evetn of that textbox I want to reference the value in the VehicleId column. How can I do that?

The RadGrid, roughly, is setup like this....

```
  <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridVehicle" runat="server"
       Skin="Office2010Silver" EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True"
       GridLines="None"
       OnItemCommand="RadGridVehicle_ItemCommand"
       OnNeedDataSource="RadGridVehicle_NeedDataSource" PageSize="50"
       OnItemDataBound="RadGridVehicle_ItemDataBound"
       OnItemCreated="RadGridVehicle_ItemCreated">
<HeaderContextMenu EnableTheming="True">
  <CollapseAnimation Type="OutQuint" Duration="200"></CollapseAnimation>
</HeaderContextMenu>
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%">
  <RowIndicatorColumn>
    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
  </RowIndicatorColumn>
  <ExpandCollapseColumn>
    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
  </ExpandCollapseColumn>
  <Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="VehicleId"
                 UniqueName="VehicleId" Display="True">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="VehicleCostColumn" HeaderText="Vendor Cost">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="VehicleCostAmt" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="VehicleCostAmt_OnTextChanged" runat="server" Width="55px"></asp:TextBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle Width="90px"/>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

So, as you can see the VehicleCostAmt textbox has an OnTextChanged event. Right now that event is coded as...

```
protected void ProductCostAmt_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
    if (txt != null)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm able to see txt.Text fine and get the value. I just want to be able to get the VehicleId value on that particular row. How can I do that?

In the past I've done something like this, but it doesn't work in this context...

```
GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
int vehicleId = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["VehicleId"].Text);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it

```
GridDataItem dataItem = txt.NamingContainer as GridDataItem;
int VehicleId = Convert.ToInt32(dataItem["VehicleId"].Text);
```

That's all!

Comment: DataKeyNames can also help: https://www.telerik.com/forums/get-datakey-from-radgrid